# Cannot find module '../../plugins/insert-concat-assets-webpack-plugin'

Tags: angular

I started my project from that seed: https://github.com/siteslave/clarity-angular4-electron

Then, I wanted to upgrade to version 5 of angular and got that below issue.

I don't know which module is asking that plugin.

I saw from angular-cli github repo, this change: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/8cea8ffdc28908b325d8a56f06ff3d626efdeb8d

Anyone has a clue?

The error:

```
$ ng serve
Cannot find module '../../plugins/insert-concat-assets-webpack-plugin'
Error: Cannot find module '../../plugins/insert-concat-assets-webpack-plugin'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object. (C:\myproject\node_modules@angular\cli\models\webpack-configs\common.js:7:47)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object. (C:\myproject\node_modules@angular\cli\models\webpack-configs\index.js:7:10)-configs\index.js:7:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
```

The package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~5.0.0",
    "@clr/angular": "^0.11.0",
    "@clr/icons": "^0.11.0",
    "@clr/ui": "^0.11.0",
    "@ngforage/ngforage-ng5": "^1.0.4",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "@webcomponents/custom-elements": "^1.0.6",
    "core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "mutationobserver-shim": "^0.3.2",
    "node-adodb": "^4.0.6",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.6.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.5.7",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.5",
    "codelyzer": "~4.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.1",
    "cpx": "^1.5.0",
    "electron": "^1.7.10",
    "electron-packager": "^10.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.5.2"
  }
```

Comment: you'd show your package.json file

Comment: Please show your package.json file, your folder structure and in which file you are trying to import the "insert-concat-assets-wepack-plugin' module

Comment: I added the package.json + which seed I started from

Comment: Man, just one question. After upgrade your angular version. did you do a `npm install` again? i see the link that you post and they delete the `insert-concat-assets-webpack-plugin` module for the `ScriptsWebpackPlugin, ScriptsWebpackPluginOptions` modules.

Comment: it's rare. it's like your `angular-cli` doesn't update `ng serve` function.

Comment: Thanks @KenrySanchez for the hint. I uninstall angular-cli another time locally and globally and the reinstallation worked! Thanks

Comment: Sure. You're welcome!!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and it took some time to get it working again. As far as I remember saving webpack as a dev dependency `npm install --save-dev webpack` and running `npm install` worked for me.
Make sure all packages are updated if possible. I used [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates). `ncu` lists all outdated dependancies and `ncu -x typescript -u -a` updates the `package.json` (excluding Typescript since Angular 5 only works with Typescript 2.5.x). After updating `package.json` you need to run `npm install`.

If that doesn't work try to make a new and clean clone of the repository and then run `ncu -x typescript -u -a` and `npm install`.

Comment: I uninstall angular-cli another time locally and globally and the reinstallation worked. But thanks about ncu. Did not know about it.

Comment: if you like ncu maybe you also want to have a look at https://david-dm.org